# SQL Having Clause with Two Counts

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns: AUTHOR and PUBLISHER.
I want to get all authors that have been published by all the authors in the table.

```
SELECT AUTHOR AS
FROM TEMP1
HAVING COUNT(AUTHOR) = 2
GROUP BY AUTHOR;
```

So this will give me the result set that I currently want because I know that there's only two publishers in the data, and they all have only published one of each author's books.

```
SELECT AUTHOR AS
FROM TEMP1
HAVING COUNT(AUTHOR) = COUNT(PUBLISHER)
GROUP BY AUTHOR, PUBLISHER;
```

This doesn't work, as it just returns all authors. I'm guessing one (or both) of the counts might not be doing what I'm hoping for because the group by is wrong?

Comment: `HAVING` goes *after* `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want authors that have all publishers in the table:

```
SELECT AUTHOR 
FROM TEMP1
GROUP BY AUTHOR;
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT PUBNAME) FROM TEMP1);
```

Comment: Correct, and that's a much better way of phrasing. I'll update my question to improve its language, and accept this answer.